# Pyqt Highlight table row

Tags: python, pyqt

How to highlight a row in pyqt table widget. I dont know the exact word for this but i want to manually higlight the row as it happens clicking over the row.

Comment: Do you mean you want to highlight the row as your *mouse hovers over*?

Answer (score 6):

In PyQt, to select and highlight a row of a QTableWidget, you need to know the row index.

Using:

```
tableWidget.selectRow(rowID)
```

should achieve this for you. However, if you mean to highlight a row on mouseover/hover, you will need to catch a signal ( I believe it is `itemActivated` ) and manipulate the styling of the QTableView item.

Answer (score 1):

Your model (a `QAbstractTableModel` derived) class should return a proper value for `Qt::BackgroundColorRole`, `Qt::ForegroundRole`, etc. roles in the method

```
QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const = 0
```

based on the actual content of the model row you want to highlight.